# Auto Login, AppDelegate to SceneDelegate, UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate to be replaced by?

Tags: ios, swift

I am facing an issue as I was trying to set up my AutoLogin feature.

I did some research on the root ViewController prior and found that instead of using AppDelegate, I now need to use the SceneDelegate for the Auto Login function. However, the following code keeps crashing my app whenever I try to sign out or sign in.

```swift
(UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).configureInitialViewController()
```

I understand that I no longer can use this as I've switched to SceneDelegate from AppDelegate. Could anyone advise on the revised code I should be using to allow me to Login and Sign Out?

My code in SceneDelegate is as follows.

```swift
func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
    configureInitialViewController()
    guard let _ = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }
}

func configureInitialViewController() {
    var initialVC: UIViewController
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Welcome", bundle: nil)

    if Auth.auth().currentUser != nil {
        initialVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: IDENTIFIER_TABBAR)
    } else {
        initialVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: IDENTIFIER_WELCOME)
    }

    window?.rootViewController = initialVC
    window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code you are not setting up your window.

```
var window: UIWindow?

func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions)
{
    guard let windowScene = scene as? UIWindowScene else {
        return
    }

    let window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Welcome", bundle: nil)

    if Auth.auth().currentUser != nil {
        window.rootViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: IDENTIFIER_TABBAR)
    } else {
        window.rootViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: IDENTIFIER_WELCOME)
    }

    self.window = window
    window.makeKeyAndVisible()
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I did set up the window. I think the issue is at where I try to run the shared.delegate (AppDelegate) code,  since where I am implementing my code now is no longer in AppDelegate but in SceneDelegate.

Comment: From which method you are accessing shared.delegate? For autoLogin your SceneDelegate method will be called by default, right? Why do you want to access it again for autoLogin?